# How do I detect Touch-specific *behaviors* in the browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, touch

Mobile Safari behaves differently from desktop browsers:

- **Scroll behavior**: the `scroll` event is fired once in the entire scroll;
- **Page zoom behavior**: the user zoom maintains the initial page width (unlike ctrl+ on the desktop), which brings problems like *unusable `position: fixed;`*

Is there a way to **detect these two problems separately** rather than relying on UA sniffing or checking for touch events?

These browsers might have other problems, if you know of any, please point them out.

Comment: Why not use a framework that already solves these issues like jQuery Mobile for example.

Comment: jQuery Mobile would be an overkill since I'm only doing feature detection. Besides, I don't know whether (or how) it can be used to detect such behaviors.